# Using a non-matlab ODE simulator to run a model created in matlab/simbiology - how to represent "repeated assignment" rules?

Tags: matlab, simulation

I am using non-matlab ODE simulation software to reproduce a model that was created with the simbiology toolbox in matlab.

One issue is the representation of repeated assignments. Is it possible to re-express repeated assignments in a way that they can be simulated in a standard Runge Kutta (or other iterative method) which only supports ODE systems? Or is it impossible re-express a model with repeated assignments as a system of ODEs?

Comment: What does "repeated assignment" refer to? Is this a technical term of simbiology, or does this refer to multiple ODE, or are there non-ODE equations involved in determining the state? In short, can you restate the question in more general mathematical terms or provide examples of code and equations?

Comment: a repeated assignment is analogous to a local variable that is defined in terms of other repeated assignments or state variables in the ode. However, my understanding is that there cannot be circular definitions of repeated assignments. For example, you can't say a = b + 1, and b = a + 1, and have them both be repeated assignments. Thus, in theory it doesn't introduce any actual state, but works as an abstraction. Because repeated assignments can be defined in terms of other repeated assignments, it seems like you basically have to do some sort of graph traversal of definitions to uncover the

Comment: underlying mathematical structure. However, I might be misunderstanding them and I hope there's a simpler solution, which is why I'm asking...

Comment: Do you have actual matlab-code or is that hidden behind some graphical user interface of the toolbox? Could you provide some typical (simplified, but working) example? Do you mean that some state `(a,b,c)` gets reassigned (simultaneously) with the new state `(b+1,a+1,a+b+c)`? Perhaps you mean something like multiple assignment like in the Fibonacci iteration, that could be formulated (in python) as `a,b = a+b,a`. Can you attach, formally, not in code, a time or iteration index to the variables, so that `a(t+dt)=b(t)+1` or `b[n+1]=a[n]+1`?

Comment: I answered your question below as best I can, but, if the software you're trying to simulate in works with SBML, you could export the SimBiology model to SBML then import it using the other software.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. In SimBiology, for most repeated assignments, you can take the assignment statement

```
x = y + z
```

and think of it as

```
dx/dt = dy/dt + dz/dt
```

and you could integrate that state. That may be the simplest way to implement what you have, keeping in mind that if you have some more complicated function that makes the assignment, you will have to carryout the chain rule correctly.

This is not how repeated assignments are handled in SimBiology. When putting together the solvers in SimBiology we can manipulate both the right hand side of the system of differential equations and the solution of the states. We implement something a bit better from the perspective of ODE solution accuracy and speed of solution, but without knowing more about your solver, I can't advise you on how to proceed.

--Andrew 
(one of the SimBiology devs)